# Increase Max length of image name of Magento 2.3.5 error message:(was not uploaded. Filename is too long; must be 90 characters or less)

Tags: magento2.3.5

When I import product data or I upload image directly to a product I get the following message
(was not uploaded. Filename is too long; must be 90 characters or less)

Recently my magento has been updated and I didn't have this problem before.

Does anyone know how I can increase the number of characters slightly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself.

The file in question is located in the following folder
vendor\magento\framework\File Uploader.php

search for the following code:

```
// account for excessively long filenames that cannot be stored completely in database
if (strlen($fileInfo['basename']) > 90) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Filename is too long; must be 90 characters or less');
```

Adjusting this file is not the best method, I have to add