# Importing images with special characters in path

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, import, csv, magento2.3.5-p1

I am trying to import a lot of images. Images for each product are placed in subfolders by product IDs and locale.

*The problem* is that each locale specific folder name starts with a caret (`^`).

Example image paths:

```
9454032/^all/my_image.jpg
9454032/^en/my_english_image.jpg
```

**What I'm getting**

```
1. Wrong URL/path used for attribute image in row(s): 1, 2 
2. Wrong URL/path used for attribute small_image in row(s): 1, 2 
3. Wrong URL/path used for attribute thumbnail in row(s): 1, 2
4. Wrong URL/path used for attribute additional_images in row(s): 1, 2
```

**What I've tried**

- Encoding `^` to `%5E`, like in URLs
- Simply removing the caret from

**What I'm sure of**

- CSV file encoding; I'm using Sublime text, besides Mac's Numbers, to verify the data
- Image path is correct, because it works without the caret in the path
- Multiple images (in `additional_images`) are separated correctly, with `|`, and specified in the importer
- There are no other special characters in the image names
- No extra slash in the beginning of the image path

**Possible solutions**

- A shell script to rename all folders containing `^`, although I'd like to avoid altering original data for consistency reasons

**References**

- https://sumankc.com/2016/07/28/wrong-urlpath-used-for-attribute-image-in-rows-magento2-product-import/

**Versions**

- Magento 2.3.5-p1
- PHP 7.3.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around it. You have to sanitize the images URLs. I've written a python script to remove non-alphanumeric characters from the full path of each image.

Also, this version of Magento limits the image name to 90 characters by default. [Some posts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316377/increase-max-length-of-image-name-of-magento-2-3-5-error-messagewas-not-upload) show a workaround for that.